# How can I optimize the expected value of a function in R?

Tags: r, optimization, constraints, probability, weibull

I have derived a survival function for a system of components (ignore the details of how this system is setup) and I am trying to maximize its expected, or more specifically, maximizing the expected value of the function:

```
surv_func = function(x,mu) = {(exp(-(x/(mu))^(1/3))*((1-exp(-(4/3)*x^(3/2)))+exp(-(-(4/3)*x^(3/2)))))*exp(-(x/(3-mu))^(1/3))}
```

and I am supposed (since the pdf including my tasks gives a hint about it) to use the function

```
optimize()
```

and the expected value for a function can be computed with

```
# Computes expected value of a the function "function"
E <- integrate(function, 0, Inf)
```

but my function depends on **x** and **mu**. The expected value could (obviously) be computed if the integral had no **mu** but instead only depended on **x**. For those interested, the **mu** comes from the fact that one of the components has a *Weibull*-distribution with parameters *(1/3,mu)* and the 3-mu comes from that has a *Weibull*-distribution with parameters *(1/3,lambda)*. In the task there is a constraint *mu + lambda = 3*, so I tought substituting the *lambda*-parameter in the second *Weibull*-distribution with *lambda = 3 - mu* and trying to maximize this problem would yield not only mu, but also lambda.

If I try to, just for the sake of learing about R, compute the expected value using the code below (in the console window), it just gives me the following:

```
> E <- integrate(surv_func,0,Inf)
Error in (function (x, mu)  : argument "mu" is missing, with no default
```

I am new to R and seem to be a little bit "slow" at learning. How can I approach this problem?

Comment: The function you provided does not depend on x.

Comment: Sorry, I´ve inserted the wrong expression by mistake. It should be fixed in a minute!

Comment: This works:
E <- integrate(surv_func,0,10,mu=1)
You could possibly make a plot of E with a range of mu-values.

Comment: Thank for the input, but it just leaves me with an error message:

"Error in f(x, ...) : unused argument (mu = 1)"

Comment: Well actually it does work, sorry. :)

Comment: So, trying different values for mu in E <- integrate(surv_func,0,10,mu=1) gives me a maximum when mu=1.5.

I get the same result for mu if i maximize the function itself using optimize(), when x=1 for example.

But when I plug in mu=1.5 in the function and compute the expected life time, is leaves me with a "non-finite" value.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your survival function is incorrect. The `exp(-(-(4/3)*x^(3/2)))` term in particular seems to be causing the problem. It is the same as `exp((4/3)*x^(3/2))`, which gets large pretty quickly and will dominate the other terms. Do `surv_func(1:10, 1.5)` to see what I mean. It should approach 0 as `x` approaches `Inf`.

Comment: Once you have the correct survival function, I believe you want to optimize `mu` after integrating out `x`, so `optim(1.5, function(mu) {-integrate(surv_func, 0, Inf, mu = mu)}, lower = 0, upper = 3)`

Comment: You were completely right. I had te wrong survival function. I did the whole thing from beginning to end and got the correct survival function. The problem was solved finally solved. Thanks for the input!